# C# Member expression Func<T,object> to a Func<T,bool> MethodBinaryExpression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, servicestack

Is it possible to convert a member epxression together with an object to a method binary expression in c#?

What i've tried so far:

```
public static void SaveBy<T>(this IDbConnection db, T obj, Expression<Func<T, object>> exp) where T : new()
{
    var com  = exp.Compile();
    if (db.Update(obj, e => exp == com.Invoke(obj)) <= 0)
    {
        db.Insert(obj);
    }
}

public static void UpdateBy<T>(this IDbConnection db, T obj, Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp) where T : new()
{
    db.Update(obj, exp);
}
```

what i am trying to achieve is make a method that can be called with

```
x.SaveBy(object,model=>model.property)
```

which will call x.Update, converting a MemberExpression into a methodBinaryExpression like this:

```
x.Update(object, model=>model.property == object.property);
```

### Half way solution

```
public static void SaveBy<T>(this IDbConnection db, T obj, Expression<Func<T, object>> exp) where T : new()
    {
        var result = exp.Compile().Invoke(obj);
        var exp2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(exp.Body, Expression.Constant(result)), exp.Parameters);
        if (db.Update(obj, exp2) <= 0)
        {
            db.Insert(obj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to call Update from SaveBy? What do you mean by 'converting'?

Comment: yes i want to call Update in the SaveBy Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create just new expression

```
model=>model.property == object.property

public static void SaveBy<T, TProp>(this IDbConnection db, T obj, Expression<Func<T, TProp>> exp) where T : new()
{
    var memberExp = (MemberExpression)exp.Body;
    var objPropExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(obj), memberExp.Member.Name);
    var equalExp = Expression.Equal(exp.Body, objPropExp);
    var exp2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExp, exp.Parameters);
    //exp2 = {model => (model.prop == value(object).prop)}

    if (db.Update(obj, exp2) <= 0)
    {
        db.Insert(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use TProp generic, it doesn't seem used anywhere? is it better then using an object?

Comment: `TProp` is used in the `exp` parameter, which in your case will be `object`.

Comment: @joelharkes, as say Rob, _TProp_ used instead _object_, so you can get real _MemberExpression_, instead expression convert to object